# Grails In Thread lazy exception while fethcing the contact

Tags: grails

## // form contact service i'm trying the executing upload process in a seprate thread Thread.start { fileHandlerService.saveUploadedFile(allData) }

```
// now in save uploadFile Method i'm getting lazy exception while i'm trying to fethc the contact from the db 
// bu usging it's email id
Contact.withTransaction {
def isObjectExists=domainClassObj.createCriteria().get() {
eq primaryColumn,fileValue
fetchMode 'groups', FetchMode.EAGER
fetchMode 'playEvents', FetchMode.EAGER
}
}

 //contact domain has many    static hasMany = [groups: Group,playEvents:PlayEvent]
 and i'm getting lazy initialization on  group and playevents while fethcing the contact object
```

Comment: If you're executing this in a separate thread, you probably won't have a Hibernate session (it gets bound to the request thread, i.e. the 'open session in view' pattern). Maybe try using Contact.withNewSession { ... } to see if that changes anything.

Comment: @rcgeorge23 thanx for you reply but i solved it using. grails executor plugin